# Reflecting the property and attribute in a custom HTMLInput Element in both directions in native JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element, native-web-component

I have a custom input box which inherits from `HTMLInputElement`:

```
class TB extends HTMLInputElement {

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['value'];
  }

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
      this.setAttribute('value', this.value);
    });
    }

    connectedCallback() {
      this.setAttribute('value', this.value);
    }

    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) { 
        this.value = newValue;
      }
  }
```

I am able to do the following:

1. Type "test" in the input

   `(tb.value && tb.value..attributes["value"])==="test`
2. Changing the attribute value to change the property

`tb.attributes["value"].value ="test" -> tb.value ==="test"`

But i cannot do the following:

```
tb.value = "test" -> tb.attributes["value"] === "test";
```

I think the solution is to override the get value() and set value(value) of the class. But I do not have any success with it.

Comment: I cannot confirm that. Even if I remove "value" from the observed Attributes Array the bounding is only from attr -> value and not from value -> attr

Comment: You're right => you'll need to define value setter and getter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You souldn't do that because it will alter the default behaviour of the `<input>` element, which is a one-way only binding from the `value` attribute to the `value` property.

Anyway, you'll need to overload the `value` setter and getter combined with `super`, taking care not to create an infinite loop with the 2 updates.

```js
class TB extends HTMLInputElement {
    static get observedAttributes() { return ['value'] }

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.addEventListener( 'input', () => this.setAttribute( 'value', super.value ) )
    }

    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) { 
        this.value = newValue
    }
    
    get value() { return super.value }

    set value( val ) {
        super.value = val
        if ( val != this.getAttribute( 'value' ) )
            this.setAttribute( 'value', val )
    }
}
customElements.define( 'my-input', TB, { extends: 'input' } )
```

```html
<input is="my-input" value="test" id=IN>
```

NB: it's a simple example where the data types are not checked.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Would it be better if I would use a custom HTMLElement with an value property instead? The element should behave like a "normal" input element

Comment: I've got no preference. It depends on what you intend to do and on who will use it and for what situation.

Comment: Is it in general "safe" to overload the property in js?

Comment: It's not unsafe per se in general

Comment: I noticed one thing. If there is no attribute value defined at the beginning, your code wouldnt't work. If I add  this.setAttribute("value",'') in the constructor it works without any probs. Thank you !

Comment: Trying to learn from the code: Is there value in overriding the existing EventHandler over adding an extra EventHandler? ``this.oninput = () => this.value = super.value;``

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman If you override the existing event handler you will remove the (maybe) existing (JS or inline) event handler definition, and you could be overriden as well. Adding an extra event listener is safer because it wont interfere with the other listeners and handler.